# « An unexpected shout-out to Halifax's historic north end [...] » : nuances dans l'expression de l'hommage ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, comparaison-de-langues, registre

Dans un article en langue anglaise sur le dévoilement du nouveau [billet de 10 $](https://www.banqueducanada.ca/billets/10vertical/) de la Banque du Canada à l'effigie de [Viola Desmond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola_Desmond) incluant une *représentation artistique d'un plan d'archives* du [*North End*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_End,_Halifax), quartier historique d'Halifax (en Nouvelle-Écosse), on dit :

> The new Canadian banknote honouring Viola Desmond had a satisfying
>   surprise for many African-Nova Scotians: an unexpected **shout-out** to
>   Halifax's historic north end, home to one of Canada's oldest black
>   communities.
>
> [ [*Viola Desmond banknote shines spotlight on Halifax's historic
>   north end*](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/nova-scotia/viola-desmond-banknote-north-end-halifax-map-1.4573407), Adina Bresge, *The Canadian Press*, 12 mars 2018, sur
>   cbc.ca, je souligne]

Les dictionnaires indiquent que le *shout-out* serait d'un registre [informel](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/shout-out) (*Dictionary.com*, voire de l'[argot](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shout-out&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) selon *AHDotEL*) pour « an expression of greeting or [praise](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/praise/603534) that is given to someone in the presence of many people » (*Merriam Learners*) et ça différerait à tout le moins à cet égard du *to [pay](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/pay) tribute/hommage to*, soit essentiellement [*rendre hommage à quelqu'un*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/tribute/619695?q=pay%20tribute#907155). Je ne sais pas si l'emploi est inhabituel ou au figuré dans l'article. On parlerait d'une forme d'*hommage public* — ici inattendu — rendu par le fait de la représentation, ou de l'expression d'une reconnaissance, d'une gratitude, soulignant une contribution, saluant, marquant le respect, témoignant de l'histoire et de l'importance de ce quartier et des gens qui l'habitent/-taient...

---

En s'appuyant surtout sur le contexte et l'extrait, traduirait-on ici le *shout-out* autrement que par l'*hommage*, peut-on évoquer la perception du geste de manière plus familière qu'avec l'*hommage* ici, comment le cas échéant et pourquoi ?

Comment: Worth noting is that this is not the most typical example of "shout-out"... There should be something verbal and public about it, as well as transitory. The most typical case might be a band member on stage giving a "shout-out" to someone to draw the audience's applause for them (the tech team, a less visible bandmate, a significant fan, the band member's wife...). I would call this a nod, homage, or tribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hommage convient bien au texte mais si l'on souhaite une expression plus familière, ce pourrait être *coup de chapeau* :

> un coup de chapeau inattendu au quartier nord historique d'Halifax

Un coup de chapeau est toutefois normalement adressé à une personne ou un groupe de personnes plutôt qu'à un lieu.

Answer (score 1):

I’m probably over thinking it, but in recognition of [the rap/hip-hop origins of the word “shout-out,”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281135) **maybe** the very use (typical or not) of “unexpected shout-out” here (instead of “unexpected recognition/acknowledgement/tribute”) was itself intended as a (arguably slightly gratuitous) veiled and/or additional “shout-out” to Black communities in general.

If this is the case (and maybe even if it isn’t), perhaps looking for how "comparable" French artists might express “shout-outs/props/big ups”(e.g. ?["{spéciale} **dédicace/s**"](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/album/special-d%C3%A9dicace-au-rap-fran%C3%A7ais-old-school/924296884?l=fr)?) could help reveal a suitable translation of the desired notion "de manière plus familière qu'avec *l'hommage.*"
 (*Special[e] dédicace au rap français old school* via *itunes.apple.com*)

See also [Kamini's Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/KAMINILEVRAI/videos/10155090639772600) from 8 months ago where that admittedly incomparable artist from Picardie seems to be using:

> **Dédicaces** aux communes du valenciennois.

to give each of those communes a "shout-out."

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with that use, seems to be like a _tribute_, your examples stand and that works ! On a side note I don't think you were over thinking it, and me trying to find something more colloquial or casual is also directly related to that, because in English-speaking Canada it's still English but how that would work in French in a way which achieves what this might have been trying to achieve is no small feat. Anwyays, thanks!