# Comment « (donner) un coup de chapeau » et « tirer son chapeau à qqn. » se compareraient-ils ?

Tags: sens, expressions, usage, locutions, ellipse

[Ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29384) on a mentionné le *coup de chapeau* (1634 chez [Corneille](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Galerie_du_Palais)) en substantif, que [Larousse en ligne](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chapeau/14674/locution?q=coup%20de%20chapeau#152307) définit comme le/l' « salut donné en soulevant son chapeau ; hommage, témoignage d'admiration, de considération » et le TLFi comme l' « Hommage que l'on rend à quelqu'un ou à quelque chose » On donne le syntagme au pluriel *donner des coups de [chapeau](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chapeau)* pour *saluer* au TLFi. Le type de [*coup*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coup) dont il s'agit c'est celui « [Avec une idée de simple mouvement] Mouvement d'un organe, d'une partie du corps, d'un élément et de tout ce qui est susceptible de servir d'instrument » (TLFi *coup* B.).

Par ailleurs on a « *Tirer son chapeau à quelqu'un*, lui reconnaître une supériorité, un mérite » ([Larousse en ligne](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chapeau/14674/locution?q=tirer%20son%20chapeau#152311)), qu'on trouve aussi dans une section de locutions familières au TLFi : « *Tirer son chapeau. Chapeau bas* ou absol. *chapeau!* Pour exprimer l'admiration : 21. *Je vous tire mon chapeau jusqu'à terre, ma charmante, pour votre exploit d'hier.* (M. de Guérin) [...] 22. [...] Chapeau bas, messieurs! (Camus) ».  Et qu'on trouve aussi dans une [liste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chapeau) de syntagmes avec le premier : « *porter la main à son chapeau, soulever, ôter, tirer son chapeau, donner des coups de chapeau* (pour saluer); *tendre son chapeau* (pour mendier) » (TLFi).

---

Comment se comparent-ils ; ont-ils des fonctions différentes :

- Au figuré, le *coup de chapeau* a-t-il une forme verbale, s'agit-il
  bien de *(donner (un (coup de (chapeau))))* ; comment le sujet verbalise-t-il
  son action à la première personne du singulier (comme *je vous tire
  mon chapeau*), ou est-ce que ça s'exprime toujours sans verbe, avec ou sans l'article indéfini, est-ce
  que ça se réduit aussi à « chapeau (bas) ! » ?
- *Reconnaître un mérite à quelqu'un*, lui *tirer son chapeau*, n'est-ce pas là l'essence de la sémantique de l'[hommage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hommage), le
  *coup de chapeau* : y a-t-il bien une différence de sens ; autrement peut-on généralement qualifier le lien entre les deux ou leurs types
  d'emplois respectifs, est-ce autre chose que la différence entre un
  syntagme et une locution verbale (figée) ?

Comment: I think it's what differs "tips fedora" from "hats off" ? or m I wrong ?

Comment: the idiom "tips fedora" doesn't just mean to mock restrictedly to this urban difinition, it takes other dimensions like "to pay recognition" or "to salute" someone.

Comment: @Abra001 I hear you, I'm not a native speaker and I don't mean to make any assertions about English language usage, my point is that meaning is only one element. I understand both expressions perfectly in context, they're connected in terms of meaning yet not interchangeable. Just curious about why and how.... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After thinking about it, I would suggest this: 
“Je lui tire mon chapeau”, “je vous tire mon chapeau” is the expression used when you personally want to say how impressedyou are by someone for doing something. It is used in conversation, to say, my hat off to you, Way to go! Kudos to you!

“Un coup de chapeau” conveys the same feeling, but I have seen it in articles, or mentions on the TV: “un grand coup de chapeau á Mr or Mme X for raising so much money for the Red Cross”. The author or anchor person is not speaking personally, but on behalf of a larger - not specially defined -group: a salute to what should be generally considered as an achievement. 
You never hear “tu lui tires ton chapeau”. And you never hear “les Français lui tirent leur chapeau”. With the verb phrase, it is personal. Un coup de chapeau is exactly the same sentiment, but when you are not speaking for yourself. Some columns in newspapers would have the title: “coup de chapeau à...” : special kudos, salute to...

Of course, you can also personally say: “je pense que cette personne mérite un coup de chapeau”: you take your hat off to him/her and think others should do too!

Comment: Thank you! So the _same sentiment_, personal vs. s.o. else's, l'article défini _un_... Do you think that the _coup de chapeau_ used in that fashion is still associated with the verb _donner_, like the literal meaning (_Lysandre sort de chez Célidée, et passe sans s’arrêter, leur donnant seulement un coup de chapeau._, ds. Corneille, _La Galerie du Palais_, description de la scène), irrespective of whether it can be used with other verbs like _mériter_ you suggested?

Comment: Améraldor, I wrote you an answer but it appears to be far too long for comment boxes. I am completely new to the forum, so I don't know whether to post it in a new answer, or edit my first post and add there. What do you recommend?

Comment: Thanks fpr that advice . I think I may have just unlocked the chat option you describe. Back ro your question, I shortened my answer: yes, Donner (un coup de chapeau) is still used, except... only figuratively! "Nous allons donner un coup de chapeau à..." (even "faire" un coup de chapeau, I think I have heard), but now it is a show of respect not necessitating a physical hat. I think if you heard someone saying "il m'a donné un coup de chapeau ce matin", you'd want to tease the person and ask them to elaborate: "what do you mean, did he hit you? " 